# Disable checkboxes in a table based on formvalues angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, angular7

I have a Form field named **Value**.
[image]

I have a **add** button which duplicates the form.

I have a **table** button which shows and a **back** button to hide the table.(Forget abt the delete button)

[image]

The table has a column that is full of checkboxes. Now in the table, I will click as many checkboxes as the value I entered in the value-form.

[image]

Say for example if I had entered 2 in that form I can click up to 2 checkboxes in that table.

After that then I come back to the form by clicking the **back** button.

**My problem:**

Now my problem is When I click ***add*** button again and if I duplicate another **value** form and enter another value 3 and if I go check the table you can see that the checkboxes are unchecked. Instead what I want is that the checkboxes which I have checked earlier before should be disabled.

I have explained my problem as clearly as I could. If you have a doubt about my question please comment. Thanks.

Note: In my stackblitz I have posted a sample of my code in a simple(without rich UI) way

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g8cty1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my understanding you want to keep your checkboxes checked even after table closed and reopened,

You can do this with event binding:

```
<td>
    input  type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" 
      (change)="addCheckValue(i,list.isTicked)"
      [checked]="list.isTicked"
      [disabled]="list.isDisabled">
  </td>


  <td *ngIf="list.isDisabled">
            Already disabled
    </td>



addCheckValue(index,isChecked){
    if(isChecked === undefined){
      isChecked = true
    }
    this.listes[index].isTicked = isChecked;

  }



//disabled checked boxes on close 
this.listes = this.listes.map(e => {
      if (e.isTicked === true) {
        e.isDisabled = true;
      }
      return e;
});
```

[your edited repo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h6fbzu?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: When we click the checkboxes and go back and come again I want the checkboxes to be disabled @shashan

Comment: Like for example if I click 2 checkboxes and then go back and duplicate my form and after entering a value in that when I go back again to my table the already checked checkboxes should be disabled(with a message near checkbox saying that its disabled) Thats my issue

Comment: @Leno hi yes I updated the repo and edited my answer. added disable on close

Comment: Hey thanks but is there any way to add a message near the checkbox saying"already selected" or something like that? Mudincha adhayum pannunga@Shashan

Comment: I have tried doing that showing message but its showing for all values. @shahshan You can check what I tried here  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uje3g9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @Leno yes can do I updated the answer, check edited repo link

Comment: Thanks I have accepted this answer and upvoted.@shahshan I am trying to display a toastr message if I check more number checkboxes than the number I enter in that particular value form. I have tried a code.Its counting every check or click on checkbox. Can u pls check my code  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sypjzk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @Leno appreciate it. Will try but not sure what you are trying to achieve

Comment: See for example the value I enter in the form is 2. Then in that table at the top my value will be set as 2. What I want is that If I check more than 2 checkboxes I need a toastr message. This is the thing I am struggling with.

Comment: In that stackblitz I got the value of form using ngmodel and I used a count variable in addCheckValue function to take number of chekbox click and then compare it with the value to set a toatsr. But what it did was the count was increased depending upon the number of clicks. It didnt go well . I was hoping if u can help @shashan